# Best setup practice to divide network to privae and public, on possible config?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, cable, subnet

I have a network under one wireless router, connected to many devices. I'd call it main network, and I want this to be private network.

But then I want to extend this network so anyone can access it, but no access to my main network.

So far this is what I could think of the network diagram, in style of tree (lv 0,1,2,3, lv 2 is private, lv 3 is public).

[image: 1]

At the place I want to extend my network, currently I have one wired-connected PC.
It leaves me with 3 options :

1. [Blue] install new wireless extender/repeater, connect wirelessy direct to main router

   - how to divide network?
2. [Red] install wireless PCI card on wired PC, let public access via PC-as-router

   - what is the drawbacks, pros/cons? power, time, etc.
3. [Green] install new wireless router, and wire-connect PC to router, but the router position will be under desk where the cable comes from.

   - again, how to divide the network so PC still connected to main network?

If possible, I want to public network come through login interface before got access to internet. (Having different IP too from private network)

So, which should I set up? What additional things should I consider?

Comment: Is there a reason for this to be so complicated? Are you familiar with the guest WiFi feature of most modern home routers?

Comment: repeater / pci card are cheaper than router, if it possible I want to surpress budgets and I didn't really want to mix private (home) network with public (shop) network...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide your network into a private network and a guest network, I would replaced your wireless router with a new one that support guest networks, or has the options to create two (or more) seperat networks. That would be easy, and you will prevent possible problems like double NATing and two WiFi nets.

Mikrotik routers are cheap, but feature-rich.

Comment: currently using hAP Lite rb941, but it didn't cover areas which public user could reach. on that area currently could be reached over LAN cable, and a PC connected to it.